# Why do prints to console get mixed up when doing parallel computations?

Tags: parallel-processing, f#, console

While running some code that performs parallel computations the output becomes garbled: different messages get mixed up. Here is a sample:

```
Iteration 1
Iteration
Iteration 23 of 19 - Calculating P&L for test window ending at 10/28/1968 12:00:00 AM

 of
Iteration 4
Iteration  of
Iteration 5
Iteration
Iteration 19 - Calculating P&L for test window ending at  of 19 - Calculating P&L for test window ending at 5/29/1974 12:00:00 AM
6 of 878/18/1971 12:00:00 AM19 - Calculating P&L for test window ending at 3/4/1977 12:00:00 AM


 of 19 of
 of 19 - Calculating P&L for test window ending at 6/25/1985 12:00:00 AM
```

When running the same program sequentially the console output comes out nice, with no garbling.

Printing to the console is done by this function:

```
let windowTrainTest (comm: Communication) critFoo count (model: IModel) (assets: Assets) (paramList: Parameters list) =
    // Deleted some code here
    if comm = Verbose then
        let msg1 = sprintf "\nwindowTrainTestPandL: First date: %A, Last date: %A\nBest Criterion: %.2f\n" fDate lDate bestCriterion
        let msg2 = sprintf "Best Parameters: %A\n" bestParameters 
        printfn "%s" <| msg1 + msg2

    (pandl, wgts), bestParameters, ( ["Criterion", bestCriterion]            |> Map.ofList,
                                     ["FirstDate", fDate; "LastDate", lDate] |> Map.ofList )
```

Parallelization is done by this portion of the program:

```
let pSeqMapi f (xs: seq<'T>) = xs |> PSeq.mapi f

let trainTest n i (trainSize, fullSize) =
        let takenAssets = assets |> Assets.take (min fullSize len)
        lastDate takenAssets
        |> printfn "\nIteration %d of %d - Calculating P&L for test window ending at %A\n" (i + 1) n
        paramList
        |> windowTrainTest comm' critFoo trainSize model takenAssets

    let mapTrainTest (initSizes: (int * int) list) =
        let f = trainTest initSizes.Length
        match calcType with
        | PSeq -> initSizes |> pSeqMapi f |> List.ofSeq
        | _    -> initSizes |> Seq.mapi f |> List.ofSeq
```

Is there a way to avoid this kind of behavior, for example by flushing the message to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution, and it does not require locks. I replaced the lines

```
lastDate takenAssets
|> printfn "\nIteration %d of %d - Calculating P&L for test window ending at %A\n" (i + 1) n
```

with

```
let msg = sprintf "\nIteration %d of %d - Calculating P&L for test window ending at %A\n" (i + 1) n (lastDate takenAssets)
printfn "%s" msg
```

I leave to those more knowledgeable to offer an explanation.

Comment: I think it's because `printfn "%s" msg` would be equivalent with `Console.WriteLine(msg)` in C#. While `printfn "\nIteration %d of %d - Calculating P&L for test window ending at %A\n" (i + 1) n` would be like multple call to `Console.Write`

Write to console is thread safe, hence the result I think.

Answer (score 6):

Parallel computations run on different threads, and if one thread is interrupted in the middle of a `printfn` and a second thread runs a `printfn` before the first thread gets run again, then their outputs will be interleaved.

The simplest way to deal with this is to create a new function that will use the `lock` keyword around `printfn` invocations:

```
let lockObj = new obj()
let lockedPrintfn msg = lock lockObj (fun _ -> printfn msg)
```

Then replace all your `printfn` calls with `lockedPrintfn` and you should get the serialized output you're expecting. Your performance will suffer just a little since your threads will occasionally be spending some time waiting for the printfn lock, but as long as your computations take significantly longer than the time spent printing output, you shouldn't actually notice the slightly-slower performance.

Comment: Note that the lock object *needs* to be created outside the `lockedPrintfn` function. If you create the lock object inside the function, you'll end up locking on a *different* object each time, which is pointless and is effectively not a lock at all.

Comment: Note, that **if** *(cit.) ".. if one thread is interrupted in the middle of .. and a second thread runs a .. before the first thread gets run again, then .."* such code is **not** running a trully [Parallel]-mode of computation, but is subject to a **just-[Concurrent]** scheduling, depending on many external concurrent factors ( avoiding the net-effect of [Parallel]-scheduling theory ). ( Vendor-optimising-)-superscalar pipelined processor architectures aim at different targets, than the [Parallel]-computing & it is indeed hard to circumvent hard-wired tricks in just-[Concurrent] CPUs

Comment: ... what? Yes, the threading model in .Net is concurrent rather than using true parallelism. But apart from that, I have only the **vaguest** idea of what you just said, @user3666197. I think you compressed too much and I got lost along the way. Would you mind re-writing your comment in a Gist or something, where you're not limited to 600 characters, and then posting a link to that Gist?

Comment: A look into https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info + there cited resources? + Published CPU silicon-architectures Data-Sheets on ILPx / super-scalar pipelines branch-(mis)-prediction costs ( stalls ) etc, all that need to be taken into account if professional HPC-tuned code-sections are to be crafted for as smooth as achievable ( not-destroyed-by silicon-based multi-stage pipelines hard-wired policies' side-effects ) [Parallel]-execution runs? Parallel computations are simply by far not any bunch of just-[Concurrent] threads. This is industry-wide granted.

Comment: Still having a hard time understanding you; maybe it's just your unique [writing] style that's throwing me off. :-) Anyway, this question is from someone who (based on other questions he's asked) seems to be a relative beginner, so I think an in-depth discussion of the difference between concurrent and truly-parallel programming models should perhaps be held somewhere else, since it's probably going to be of no benefit to the OP.

Comment: @rmunn - Your solution did not work. I tried it putting the two lines you provided in several locations: 1) In another module, 2) In the same module, 3) Inside the function where the call to printfn was originally. Of course in all cases I called lockedPrintfn instead of printfn. By accident I found a solution which, surprisingly, does not need a lock. I replaced the code in the question with 
`let msg =
            sprintf "\nIteration %d of %d - Calculating P&L for test window ending at %A\n" (i + 1) n (lastDate takenAssets)
printfn "%s" msg`

Comment: @rmunn - Thanks for the suggestion. I answered my own question. Sorry for the bad formatting in my previous comment. I do not know how to nicely format code in a comment.